# Has anyone used Ford Fulkerson's algorithm in OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl, ford-fulkerson

I have a problem that can be modelise with a graph, need to implement it with opl and apply a maximization with Ford Fulkerson's algorithm. I didn't find anything made with opl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ford Fulkerson is a technique to solve max flow.

Linear programming is a given technique to tackle max flow

Python CPLEX example in https://gist.github.com/ZaydH/b1b09deb1873d8018fdd7cce139d0878

can be rewritten in OPL CPLEX:

```
{string} nodes={"s","a","b","c","e","t"};

tuple edge
{
  key string o;
  key string d;
  float capacity;
}

{edge} edges with o,d in nodes=
{
  <"s","a",1>, 
  <"s","b",9>, 
  <"s","c",9.5>,
  <"a","e",2>, 
  <"b","e",5>, 
  <"b","t",4>, 
  <"c","b",2>, 
  <"c","t",3.5>, 
  <"e","t",3>
};

dvar float+ flow[e in edges] in 0..e.capacity;

maximize sum(e in edges:e.o=="s") flow[e];

subject to
{
  // flow conservation
  forall(n in nodes diff {"s","t"}) 
    flowConservation:
      sum(e in edges:e.o==n) flow[e]==sum(e in edges:e.d==n) flow[e];
}

execute
{
  for(var e in edges)
   writeln(e.o," -> ",e.d," : ",flow[e]);
}
```

which gives

```
// solution (optimal) with objective 10.5
s -> a : 0
s -> b : 7
s -> c : 3.5
a -> e : 0
b -> e : 3
b -> t : 4
c -> b : 0
c -> t : 3.5
e -> t : 3
```

Comment: A bit late sorry, thanks !